# console.log returns value, the return statement is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets

So I'm receiving data from Google spreadsheets. I need to map over them (employees), then format the date I'm receiving (MomentJS), then compare that date with an existing list of dates stored in another array (testArr) and if any of them matches, I need to return the name of the employee (x.name)

When I console.log() I am getting the correct values, but not when I return.
When I return I get undefined, because I'm using the .map function I guess, but what's the alternative.

This is my first Stackoverflow question ever, so thank you so much in advance :)

```
let testArr = [3-2011, 5-2017, etc ...];

const finalForamting = () => {
    return (employees.map(emp => {
         testArr.filter(item => {
             if(moment(emp.startdate).format('M-YYYY') === item) {
                  console.log(emp.name) --> TOM, MARK, ETC ...   
                  return emp.name  ------>      undefined
             }
         })
    )
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create an empty arry at first, then push the names that interest you when they fit your condition.

Plus a few improvements:

1) use [isSame](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) to compare momentjs date

2) use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one item fits a certain condition

```
const result = [];

employees.forEach(emp => {
  if(testArr.some(item => moment(emp.startDate).format('M-YYYY').isSame(item)) {
    result.push(emp.name);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

PS: Welcome to SO :)

Comment: ahhh, now I got another issue. Now I need to remove employees from that result array which have an item.endDate property higher than the currently selected month.


employees.forEach(emp => {
                    if(testArr.some(item => (moment(emp.enddate).format('M-YYYY') > item ))) {
                        result.pop(emp);
                          }
                        });

I'll post the question now

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606016/how-can-i-remove-employees-from-the-array-that-have-enddate-property-higher-than)

Answer (score 0):

It's not how `filter` function works. Please update your code as below

```
...
testArr.filter(item => moment(emp.startdate).format('M-YYYY') === item)
...
```