# How can i remove employees from the array that have endDate property higher than current selected month?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-sheets-api

The data is coming from Google Sheets API, hence `employees.stratdate`, `employees.enddate` etc.

I need to be able to display only the employees that used to work in a selected month. If they don't work anymore, but used to work then, they should be listed, if they stopped working before the selected month, they shouldn't be listed.

THERE ARE 2 SHEETS: 
a) ONE HAS TWO COLUMNS YEAR AND A MONTH -->

**2011 March -> reports**
b) THE OTHER ONE HAS ON CONTAINING DATE FORATED AS:

**03-24-2011 -> employees [startdate & enddate formated like this]**

That's why that silly attempt of formatting ...

```
const {employees, reports} = this.props;  

   const monthsFormated = reports.map(item => {return item.month});
   const yearsFormated = reports.map(item => {return item.year});

   const employeeStart = employees.map(item => {return item.startdate});
   const employeeEnd = employees.map(item => {return item.enddate});

   const monthNamesToNumbers = () => {
       let extraFormatting = [];
       for (let i=0; i<monthsFormated.length; i++) {
        extraFormatting.push(moment().month(monthsFormated[i]).format("M"));
       }
       return extraFormatting;
    }   

    // FROMATING DATES COMING FROM EMPLOYEES-TEMPLATE    
    let finalReportsFormatting = _.zip(yearsFormated, monthNamesToNumbers())
    .map((value) => {
    let test;
    return test = (value[1] + '-' + value[0])
    });


    let employeeArr = employees.map(item => {
        return moment(item.startdate).format('M-YYYY')
     })         

    let newArr = Array.from(finalReportsFormatting).map(item => {
        return item
    })

    let testArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < employeeArr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
            if (employeeArr[i] === newArr[j]) {
                testArr.push(newArr[j])
              }
            }    
        }

        const result = [];
            employees.forEach(emp => {
                if (testArr.some(item => moment(emp.startdate).format('M-YYYY') == item) &&
                    testArr.some(item => (moment(emp.enddate).format('M-YYYY') > item))) {
                    result.push(emp);
                }
            });
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE:)

Comment: What is `employeeArr`, is it the same as `employees`? And what is `newArr`? Can you give some more context to your code?

Comment: let employeeArr = employees.map(item => {
            return moment(item.startdate).format('M-YYYY')
         })         

THIS IS JUST FOR fORMATTING REASONS . DIFFERENT COLUMNS ORDERS, SLASHES, NUMBERS, LETTERS, ETC ... SHEETS ARE A MESS

 let newArr = Array.from(finalReportsFormatting).map(item => {
            return item
        })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about simply adding the employees that correspond during the first loop:

```
employees.forEach(emp => {
    if (testArr.some(item => moment(emp.startdate).format('M-YYYY') == item) &&
      testArr.some(item => (moment(emp.enddate).format('M-YYYY') > item))) {
        result.push(emp);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still getting all workers from the books!
Let me post the entire code so maybe it would be more clear!
I'll edit this question right now, as clearly as i can ...
Thank you man !!!

Comment: No errors because you helped me with the last answer big time.
What you did with employees, I need to do with reports too and then compare them in a way that only employees are shown that worked in that particular month ->> that's coming from the reports sheets and it's formatted in 'finalReportsFormatting' and eventually in the newArr ...

Does that make any sense? I'm so tired man.
I need to finish this. Thank you! You already helped.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you,

There is a method in javascript arrays that will help you. As MAP, that iterate every item on an array, exits the array method [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

On the last iteration you should use filter and map instead of the forEach

Something like this:

```
var filteredEmployees = employees.filter(function(){
   // your filter here
}).map(...);
```

You can separate the callback in diferent functions to make your code more simple. Or you can separate the filter and the map in different declarations.

```
var filteredEmployees = employees.filter(function(){
   // your filter here
});
var mapEmployees = filteredEmployees.map(...);
```

Maybe this code isn't that you are looking for, but for sure do your code more clear and easy to manage.